# Где ошибка в моем коде?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
$.get("https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Safari%20Mesh%20%28Field-Tested%29", function(data) {

//var id = $(".market_listing_row:first", data).attr("id").substring(8),
    //price = parseFloat($(".market_listing_price_with_fee:first", data).html().replace(",", "."));

var g_sessionID = data.match(/g_sessionID = "(.*?)"/)[1],
        listingid = data.match(/"listingid":"(.*?)"/)[1],
            balance = data.match(/"wallet_balance":(.*?),/)[1],
                wallet_currency = data.match(/"wallet_currency":(.*?),/)[1],
                    converted_price_per_unit = data.match(/"converted_price_per_unit":(.*?),/)[1],
                        converted_fee_per_unit = data.match(/"converted_fee_per_unit":(.*?),/)[1],
                            price = (+converted_price_per_unit + +converted_fee_per_unit);


            $('#w').html(

            g_sessionID + "<br>" + listingid + "<br>" + wallet_currency + 
            "<br>" + converted_price_per_unit + "<br>" + converted_fee_per_unit + 
            "<br> if (" + balance + " > " + price + "}"

            );

        if (balance >= price && price <=  5.4*100) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://steamcommunity.com/market/buylisting/" + listingid,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                sessionid: g_sessionID,
                currency: wallet_currency,
                subtotal: converted_price_per_unit,
                fee: converted_fee_per_unit,
                total: price,
                quantity: 1
            },
                crossDomain: true,
                xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                success: function(data){ alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data ); }
            })

            $('#wrapper').html("Success !");

        }}, 'html');
```

Все переменные получены и выводятся. Все переменные верные. Сообщение `Success !`  выводится. Но `ajax` запрос ничего не делает. Т.е. не дает никакого результата. Запрос взят из [этой](https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/javascript/market.js?v=Bl5EpQEMKyyh&l=russian) страницы.

Может кто-то указать на ошибку и как ее исправить ?

Comment: Так ajax запрос у вас не отправляет, или не принимает данные?

Comment: @Visman Не отправляет.

Comment: Так может он все-таки отправляется, но вы забыли указать функцию обработки ответа и из-за этого не видите результата?

Comment: @Visman В результате с моего баланса должны списаться деньги.

Comment: Открывайте консоль как @TwoRS предложил и смотрите ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте консолью/алертом listingid. Если есть, то на сервере вообще пост запрос по этому адресу?  Выведите,какой-нибудь алерт перед аяксом, что б узнать-доходит выполнение до этого места. Потом консолью выведите data

Comment: Я это уже написал. Все выводится. Все переменные есть. На счет адреса запроса, я дал ссылку на js файл в котором есть этот запрос (Можно найти с помощью Ctrl+F). Где он (По моему) в точности как у меня.

Comment: Проверьте вообще-получаете Вы данные... $.ajax({
  url: "........some.php",type: "POST",
  success: function(data){
    alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
  }
});

Comment: Я их, вообще-то, пытаюсь отправить.

Comment: Да. Ну так подставить к Вашему коду ещё success: function(data){ alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data ); } }  ,т.к. Вы не видите- получили Вы вообще что-то или нет. А вот если-нет , то уже потом будем отталкиваться- в чём дело. И проверьте перед отправкой data. Со значениями ли она или нет? Вы в браузере видите отправленный пост запрос или там ничего нет?

Comment: Я поставил вашу ф-ю `success: function(data){ alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data ); }`, но алерта не было. Возможно я не туда ее пихнул (Я обновил код, посмотрите, туда ли я ее всунул). И разве ф-я которая должна отправлять значения может их принимать ?

Comment: Нет. Должна быть на одном уровне с url пример - http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.ajax/   это функция обратного вызова. Т.е. когда успешный запрос и пришли данные (а они могут прийти и через секунду..2..и т.д.) и data покажет ответ.  Перепишите это и вообще посмотрите в браузере-есть ли запрос по Вашему адресу

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26526/discussion-between-slavik-okara-and-twors).

Comment: Добавьте кроме функции success еще функцию fail , которая расскажет вам,что пошло не так. Одна из них в любом случае должна отработать. А еще во всех нормальных браузерах в консоли есть вкладка network (или сеть,или еще что нибудь в этом роде). Там тоже можно узнать, что же случилось с вашим запросом