# Кросс доменный запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Мне нужно составить кросс доменный запрос. На странице, куда я пытаюсь отправить данные есть вот такой заголовок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю из-за него не проходит запрос.

Сам запрос такого плана:

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: "https://steamcommunity.com/market/buylisting/" + listingid,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                    sessionid: g_sessionID,
                    currency: wallet_currency,
                    subtotal: converted_price_per_unit,
                    fee: converted_fee_per_unit,
                    total: price,
                    quantity: 1
                },
                    success: function(data){ alert(data); },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }

                })
```

Все переменные есть и соответствуют запросу.

Как быть ?

Comment: речь, видимо, про *http*-заголовок [*referer*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)?

Comment: @alexander barakin, вероятно речь о кросс доменном запросе ajax. В продолжение этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439407/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, Да.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие, так как на дубль этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443637/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC был получен правильный ответ по мнению автора до того как дубль был закрыт.