# Помогите разобраться с ajax запросом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пишу расширение для google chrome. С него выполняю запрос.
На странице, куда я пытаюсь отправить данные есть вот такой заголовок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю из-за него не проходит запрос.

Сам запрос такого плана:

```
               $.ajax({
                    url: "https://steamcommunity.com/market/buylisting/" + listingid,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        sessionid: g_sessionID,
                        currency: wallet_currency,
                        subtotal: converted_price_per_unit,
                        fee: converted_fee_per_unit,
                        total: price,
                        quantity: 1
                    },
                    success: function(data){ alert(data); },
                    crossDomain: true,
                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }

                })
```

Все переменные есть и соответствуют запросу.

Как быть ?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это дубль вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439442/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Сервер стима блокирует любые межсайтовые запросы, кроме перечисленных доменов. Это защита от XSS.

Comment: возможно вы знаете, STH плагин для стима как-то выполняет этот запрос.

Comment: Поковыряйте исходники, беглым взглядом кажется, что плагин работает через API. API открыто для запросов с других доменов. Оно для того и сделано. По поводу API Steam ничего не знаю. На поставленный вопрос я ответил. :)